Pico W Ducky - UK Keyboard Layout converting Backslash ( \ ) to Hash ( # )
I have setup a Pico Ducky using Pico W. I have been able to get some test scripts to work. I am working on a simple use case where a text file is saved to a location on the target machine. I am using the UK Keyboard layout as provided by Neradoc. Below is my duckyscript that i am transferring to the target machine. However, the backslashes are being converted to # when entered onto the target machine via the Pico Ducky.
I tried working around this by updating the keycodes for backslash to input alt + 9 + 2 .To do this, I adjusted the keycode_win_uk and keyboard_layout_win_uk py files but no joy.
I am wondering if anyone has found a fix for backslashes on UK Keyboard layouts?
DELAY 500
GUI r
DELAY 500
STRING powershell
ENTER
DELAY 500
STRING $filepath = "$env:userprofile\Documents"
ENTER
DELAY 500
STRING New-Item -Path "$filepath\secrets.txt" -ItemType File -Force
ENTER
DELAY 500
STRING $doc = "$filepath\secrets.txt"
ENTER
DELAY 500
STRING Set-Content -Path $doc -Value 'These are my secrets'
ENTER


Your posting so-far does not give me confidence that any answer I give will be used for good and not evil...

I am completing a Masters in Cyber Security and am working on a project focused on Penetration Testing. I am identifying weaknesses and vulnerabilities that could be exploited whilst also documenting how such vulnerabilities can be closed. As with anything in the domain of pen testing or hacking, it should only ever be done with users permissions and not for malicious purposes. I am purely trying to learn

Okay that works for me - do you know exactly what firmware you're running?

From what I can tell, the BashBunny+RubberDucky Encoder program converts each character read from your script file to a USB HID keyboard key-code using its own table, and it always converts \ to 0x31, whereas when I press the \ key on my UK keyboard I can see it has scancode 0xDC - my suggestion then is that you write a program that converts the keycodes in the built .bin file after you run the encoder but before writing it to the Ducky.

Thanks Dai. Based on the Keyboard Layouts and Keyboard Code scripts that have been provided by Neradoc, it looks as if the key-codes are all encoded in the python. The key codes are https://github.com/Neradoc/Circuitpython_Keyboard_Layouts/blob/main/libraries/keycodes/keycode_win_uk.py and the keyboard layouts are https://github.com/Neradoc/Circuitpython_Keyboard_Layouts/blob/main/libraries/layouts/keyboard_layout_win_uk.py

I found a work around for not using a backslash by using [System.IO.Path]::Combine($env:USERPROFILE, 'Documents')

You could have also used a forward-slash too...
